# Is there a way to pass a WebElement to javascript in Robot?

Tags: javascript, python, robotframework, selenium2library

Is there a way to pass a WebElement to javascript in Robot? My script:

```
${el} =    Get Webelement    ${locator}
Execute Javascript    ${el}.checked = true;    #not sure how to approach this bit
```

I cannot use document.getElementById("whatever") as in some certain cases there's no ID used but custom locators.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So yes, I've got the solution by combination of above:

```
Select Checkbox
    [Arguments]    ${locator}    ${timeout}=${global_timeout}
    ${tempId} =    Generate Random String    8
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    locator=${locator}    timeout=${timeout}
    ${origId} =    Get Element Attribute    ${locator}@id
    Assign Id To Element    locator=${locator}    id=${tempId}
    Execute Javascript    document.getElementById("${tempId}").checked = true;
    ${locator} =    Replace String    string=${locator}    search_for=${origId}    replace_with=${tempId}
    Assign Id To Element    locator=${locator}    id=${origId}

Unselect Checkbox
    [Arguments]    ${locator}    ${timeout}=${global_timeout}
    ${tempId} =    Generate Random String    8
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    locator=${locator}    timeout=${timeout}
    ${origId} =    Get Element Attribute    ${locator}@id
    Assign Id To Element    locator=${locator}    id=${tempId}
    Execute Javascript    document.getElementById("${tempId}").checked = false;
    ${locator} =    Replace String    string=${locator}    search_for=${origId}    replace_with=${tempId}
    Assign Id To Element    locator=${locator}    id=${origId}

Checkbox Should Be Selected
    [Arguments]    ${locator}    ${timeout}=${global_timeout}
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    locator=${locator}    timeout=${timeout}
    ${el} =    Get Webelement    ${locator}
    Should Be True    ${el.is_selected()}

Checkbox Should Not Be Selected
    [Arguments]    ${locator}    ${timeout}=${global_timeout}
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    locator=${locator}    timeout=${timeout}
    ${el} =    Get Webelement    ${locator}
    Should Not Be True    ${el.is_selected()}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible, but what you could try is, giving an id to your located element, using the keyword [Assign Id To Element](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Assign%20Id%20To%20Element) and then retrieve your element in the javascript with `document.getElementById`

Edit: If assigning an Id isn't an option, you could look into how the keyword mentioned above assigns the id to the element and implement your own keyword using the same trick, but to check your checkbox. Something like this:

```
element = self._element_find(locator, True, True)
self._current_browser().execute_script("arguments[0].checked=true;", element)
```

Comment: Not sure about this one as other parts of process on screen can potentially rely on the element ID.

Comment: Then perhaps you could write your own keyword, using the same technique as the keyword I mentioned (Assign Id To Element). Check out the source in Selenium2Library and see how it passes the web element to the javascript ( the `arguments[0]` part ). Unfortunately I don't think the `Execute Javascript` lets you pass these arguments as is.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot pass the web element to javascript. It is a python object.

However, you don't need to use javascript if you want to call a method on the object. For example, to check if the element is selected you can do `${el.is_selected()}`

The available element methods are documented here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement

Comment: Perfect, that seemed to work for checking if the checkbox is selected - is there a way how to select it using similar approach?

Comment: Or potentially, is there a way how to select that checkbox without clicking it? Cause that element is not visible. Basically, I'm looking for a way how to replace: document.getElementById("whatever").checked=true; in javascript

Comment: either the pure selenium call in this answer, or `${checked}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Checkbox Should Be Selected    ${locator}`

Answer (score 0):

```
${child}=    Execute Javascript    return arguments;     ARGUMENTS    ${child}    ${parent}
```

you can pass arguments to Executer using ARGUMENTS keyword, you can try print ${child} and see