# How to iterate over WebElements object and generate Xpath for it while executing test case?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, robotframework

In RobotFramework 5.0. I have a keyword as below:

```
Scroll To Element
    [Documentation]     Scroll to the element on a page.
    ...                 This keyword uses javascript because the internal selenium keyword gives an OutOfBounds Error
    ...                 Expects one required argument:
    ...                 -> locator    Element locator
    [Arguments]       ${locator}

    # since locators in RF have 'xpath:' as prefix, we only want the pure xpath without prefix
    ${xpath_element_to_center}=   Fetch From Right  ${locator}   :

    Execute JavaScript    window.document.evaluate("${xpath_element_to_center}",
    ...  document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.scrollIntoView(true)
```

The keyword runs as expected when I pass a locator object, but if I pass a webElement instead of locator, the Execute Javascript keyword fails.

If I were to extract a list of webElements and iterate over it such as below, it won't work:

```
@{my_elements}=  Get WebElements  ${some_locator}
FOR  ${element}  IN  @{my_elements}
    Scroll To Element    ${element}
```

I want the 'Scroll To Element' keyword to accept both locator objects and webElement objects like native RF behaviour, but the Javascript I have written only accepts pure xpath to the element. How do I extract or construct an xpath for a WebElement object while executing a test case using RF or Python or Javascript, etc?

Comment: Not possible. Workaround could be found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45739491/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-webelement-to-javascript-in-robot

Comment: It doesn't work because with the `"${xpath_element_to_center}"` you've serialized a  python object into a string (due to the quotes) - something that looks like "seleniumObject224: blahblah", while the document.evaluate() expects a proper locator. And even w/o serialization you can't pass python objects to the browser's js, as the other comment points out. You could get the type of the argument passed to the keyword - if it's string, go with the js; if WebElement - do something else.

Comment: By the way, please elaborate why the `Get WebElements` didn't work for you, it's much safer approach than the js DOM interaction; perhaps we might be able to fix it with you, and just drop the `evaluate()` approach.

Comment: @TodorMinakov So, what happens is, in the window.document.evaluate() method, I can pass a string object which looks like an xpath to any web element such as `//body`, but I cannot pass a selenium webelement (which is what I get when I iterate over @{my_elements} list) directly as it is expecting only an object's xpath.

Comment: And if I am not using the evaluate method, the inbuild robot keyword to scroll element into view always gives me an OutOfBounds error and I don't really understand why I would receive that error.

Comment: To continue on with my test scripts, I have just ignored this all together and skipped this scrolling step in my test script, but would be very helpful to figure out what is going wrong and will surely be useful in the long run. I'd hate to bother you but in case you ever make some time to check this out, I'd love to connect with you and try and solve this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "in the window.document.evaluate() method, I can pass a string object which looks like an xpath to any web element such as //body, but I cannot pass a selenium webelement" - yes, precisely, only strings that are proper xpath locators. "would be very helpful to figure out what is going wrong and will surely be useful in the long run" just create a new SO question and (hope ;)) the community will help you out. Tyr to include as much relevant info as possible - steps, screenshots, the DOM state, this will greatly increase the question's chance of answering.